# Proving inner product conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inner-products

I'm new to the concept of inner product space and was wondering if anyone cold help me here.

I believe that the inner product space is the multiplication of each corresponding entry of the two vectors and then the addition of all of these values.

So I believe to show part (a) ii., I have to say that for any length of $\vec v$ you will always have $0* \vec v_{n} =0$ and that $0+0+0+0...$ n times will always result in 0.

However for part (a) i., I don't know how to approach this at all.

Am I headed on the right track or is my thinking incorrect?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could use the fact that the zero vector is orthogonal to any vector, even itself, and hence the dot product of the zero vector and any other vector must equal to zero. However im not sure on how to answer the part ai) for you. Hope this helped at all.

Answer (score 1):

> for part (a) i., I don't know how to approach this at all

For (a) i., we have $\langle \vec u,\vec v\rangle=\vec u^T\vec v$, so $\langle M\vec u,\vec v\rangle=(M\vec u)^T\vec v.$

By a property of [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), $(M\vec u)^T=\vec u^TM^T$.

Therefore $\langle M\vec u,\vec v\rangle= \vec u^TM^T\vec v=\langle \vec u,M^T\vec v\rangle.$